# ASP.Net or Node.js in the following situation

Tags: performance, node.js, crud, asp.net-web-api

Good morning,

I am going to write a web service and I am not sure which framework would suit the situation best. I understand what Node and .Net are good at.

The client will call the services at the following stages:

App loads up - user logins in via Facebook API.

User can create an "entity". This entity will be stored in a database (SQL for .Net/ Azure table for Node) and also posted to a Facebook application (timeline stuff). User can make changes to this at any time.

User can browse Facebook Friends (Facebook API again).

Changes to the entity will be pushed to all users who have "joined" the same entity (SignalR .net/Socket.io Node).

That is the skeleton of the web services, there may be more Facebook calls or CRUD operations. Which Framework will handle this best?

Many thanks.

Comment: I would like to see some performance tests like...challenge-response times. How long does it take to send each type of server a random integer and have it return that integer back out of an average of a million calls? Great question. I feel like it won't be fully answered without performance metrics. Numbers don't lie :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any *well-written code* regardless of the framework will be able to handle it.

If you are a .NET developer I personally think type safety of C# is important so I would not go down the Azure node.js way since it will also force me to use Azure.

I would personally use ASP.NET Web API.

Comment: So you wouldn't use Node because of Azure? I would use Azure for ASP.NET too. Good points on ASP.NET too thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the mentioned WebAPI, also consider the excellent [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net/) for building a webservice.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you build your application on a solid framework, you'll be on the bright side (assuming you know how to set-up such an application in a secure and proper manner). For .NET i'd use the Web API and for node.js i'd stick with something like express/connect.

Just keep in mind that node.js and the frameworks based on it are still subject to heavy changes, whereas ASP.NET is production-safe since years.

As a bottom line, i don't think you're able to say "X is better than Y because of Z" in this scenario. It's a matter of personal preferences, infrastructure and your technical skills.

Comment: Brilliant, I shall be sticking with what I know then, .NET. Thanks!